# Xcode playground takes way too long to run

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been running Xcode with no issues, and all of a sudden playground sticks on `Running Second`, as seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEJcT.png). Occasionally Xcode "stops" responding upon the launch of the project.

This takes forever and it's very hard to get a project going due to the time it takes to get start. Any ideas? I've spent hours trying to figure things out. I'm running Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **beta** version of Xcode. The syntax checker crashed a lot on both Yosemite and El Capitan, for both beta 1 and 2. Compiler sometimes works, sometimes don't, and code works in Xcode 6 might not work correctly in Xcode 7 beta.

In the past, when Swift 1.0 beta just out, there were lots of issues like this, and some of them didn't get fixed till 1.2.

If this happens everytime, consider file a bug report to Apple so they could look into it. (I do!) Or you can provide some code you were testing so we can all have a look.

Comment: Well I'd assume it's a bug because I'm just trying to `print` a string. I'll file a report!

Comment: Did you try `Swift.print()` instead of just `print()`?